# How to access docker container service from outside world like from parent windows host machine

Tags: windows, docker, vagrant, docker-network

As part of "How to access docker container service from outside  world like from parent  windows host machine "

I followed the following  step  :

1) On windows machine(10.204.255.*/16) , I created vagrant VM (172.17.0.*/24) . Inside vagrant VM I created different  docker images based on  my requirements.

2) As part of docker image creation, created centos:6.6 images and run  installed ACE-TAO service inside that.

3) TAO service is running properly, and it is  binding with the specific container ip: specific port (like 172.17.0.10:13021)

Reference: Able to create images and run  the images to create container and  install  TAO  rpm and TAO service running successfully.
Issues is like  i'm  not able  to ping this ip from  outside world like from my windows machine

I'm  attaching my dockerfile here

```
FROM centos:6.6

MAINTAINER praveen 

WORKDIR /root/

ADD TAO-1.7.7-0.x86_64.rpm /root/TAO-1.7.7-0.x86_64.rpm

RUN rpm -ivh  TAO-1.7.7-0.x86_64.rpm

CMD ["/etc/init.d/tao", "start"]

EXPOSE 13021
```

I believe  this  is  common usecase of  docker is like : 
Installed service on  dockerized  container with are accessible from  host machine , if we try to  access with  ip:port

ACE-TAO  behavior is  like ,rpm installed to specific host ,  so we  can access corba service from  this url : corba://(tao_service_runnig_ip):(listening port) 
In order to meet this requirement , i need to access the from  host machine

Comment: I'm  able to ping  host ip in  dockerized container , but reverse not happening

Comment: The Docker host here is your VM. Can you post your `docker run` command? Assuming you published the port with `-p 13021:13021` you should be able to access it from `localhost:13021` in the VM. That's the first thing to check.

Comment: On Windows  machine  installed ubuntu VM installed and on top  of  that , i created docker image . So my host is  Windows machine .

Comment: In Ubuntu I'm able to ping  that dockerized container IP. Normally I'm running  daemon TAO  service on docker container. and i want to use that service in windows  machine like  corba:docker-ip:port

Comment: I'm using these commands  docker build --rm  -t tao/centos6.6:basic .                         
docker run  -it -p 13021:13021 tao/centos6.6:basic

Comment: What you are asking for can't be done with the [default bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#/the-default-bridge-network-in-detail).

Comment: As part  of my requirements  i cann't make  it as bridge network