# How to access the docker-container-ip:docker-container-port from outside network

Tags: docker, docker-network, private-subnet

I'm running docker setup in following way

1) On windows running the vagrant script to install ubuntu14.04 on my local VM

2) on top of VM running docker containers

Here my concern is like

My Windows machine subnet is different (like 10.204.255.*/16)

My VM subnet is different like(10.0.2.*/16)

My docker container subnet is different like(172.17.0.*/24)

If I want to  access specific container services in  VM level , i can  use them specifying like VM-ip or localhost:forwardind-port/ ;  it sounds good
If I want to access from Windows machine it'll  work same way with forwarding-port

But from windows machine, if i want to access like container-ip:container-port/ 
How can achieve this ?

Why i need to  access like this is , in my container i'm running corba specific service, those service we can access via specific service running container-ip n port

Comment: Because of my constraints , I'm not able to change VM network from  NAT->bridged

Comment: Since you have n/w constraints that prevents you from switching to bridged, I would suggest you to install Docker directly on your Windows machine. Is that possible?

Comment: You meant say docker toolbox ?

Comment: If you have latest Windows version, you wouldn't even need Docker toolbox

Comment: As per my project specification , I need to go with vagrant VM which is running on windows machine and need to install docker inside that

Comment: Please don't ask the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40218535/how-to-access-docker-container-service-from-outside-world-like-from-parent-windo) multiple times just because you didn't get an answer the first time. Or at least delete the previous question to keep things cleaner.